# How to downgrade Laravel Sail PHP version to 7.4

Tags: php, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04, laravel-sail

I am having an error when I my change my php version in docker-compose.yml form 8.1 to 7.4 it cause an error.

```
 services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
                NODE_VERSION: '14'
        image: sail-8.1/app
```

to

```
 services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/7.4
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
                NODE_VERSION: '14'
        image: sail-7.4/app
```

when running sail build --no-cache causes error:

ERROR [ 4/11] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mk

but when I return it to 8.1 it works smoothly.

Comment: I am having problem with PDOException after implicit commit. that is why I am reverting to older version of php. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/35380